# Make Lighttpd treat .CSS files as .PHP files

Tags: php, lighttpd

I want files with a .CSS extension to be treated as PHP, and parsed/executed as if they were .PHP files (in addition to retaining the default behavior of parsing .PHP files as PHP).

Is there an easy way to do this with Lighttpd?